# jquery: how to check if radio group tick pattern is correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a form with 3 questions using radio groups. After ticking the 3 radio boxes a hidden div then should appear. The condition for the div to appear should be if the first question is "NO" and the rest of the 2 questions "YES". im new to Jquery, please help?

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="5">
    <tr>
    <td>Question 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="q1" value="yes" />Yes
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="no" />No</td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
    <td>Question 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" name="q2" value="yes" />Yes
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="no" />No</td>
    </tr>


<tr>
    <td>Question 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" name="q3" value="yes" />Yes
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="no" />No</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Show us what you tried so far..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it clearly shows OP has not even tried to search the documentation. The question has no specific code example or specific error.

Comment: What div should appear?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/jkrom0pe/

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$('input').on('change' , function(){

  if($('input[name="q1"]:checked').val() == 'no' && $('input[name="q2"]:checked').val() == 'yes' && $('input[name="q3"]:checked').val() == 'yes'){

    $('body').append('<div id="testDiv">A div</div>');

  }
  else{

    $('#testDiv').remove();

  }

})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yann86/70kwo1oe/